# qlik sense - concat the same column few times

Tags: concatenation, pivot-table, qliksense

I have to do this exercise and I need your help.

I have a table with this rows:
**Table Emp: Id, Name, Country, Age.**
I have loaded this table twice

The second table is **Table Emp2: Id2, Name2, Country2, Age2.**
(with the  same values like table emp1)

I want to create a pivot table, the dimension will be emp.id. the measure will be the concatinate of all the id's of the employees in table emp2 that have the same **name** and **country**.

Do I need to use the concat function? and how to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Probably its easier to solve this in the script first.

(looking at the script below) We can see that there is one match - from `Employee` table the row with `Id = 1` is matching with `Employee2` rows `Id2 = 1` and `Id2 = 2`

To get the match we can create additional table `Employee_Link` which will contain the link between `Id` and `Id2`.

To form the table we are loading (from `Employee` table) `Id` and concatenating `Country` and `Name` fields to form new field `NameCountryLink` (im using [AutoNumberHash128](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/April2020/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/CounterFunctions/autonumberhash128.htm) function to get number representation of the concatenated string)

The resulted table we are `left join` to the same table structure but sourced from `Employee2` table.

The final table will contain only the matches between `Employee` and `Employee2` tables.

Once we have the data we can create the UI table with dimension `Id` and measure `concat(distinct IdMeasure, ',')`

And the result will be:

[image: Table result]

As you can see only the first row contains the concatenated values and there is no match for `Id = 2`

```sql
Employee:
Load * Inline [
Id, Name , Country , Age
1 , Adam , Country1, 20
2 , John , Country2, 21
3 , Ana  , Country3, 22
4 , Rose , Country4, 23
5 , David, Country5, 24
];

Employee2:
Load * Inline [
Id2, Name2, Country2, Age2
1  , Adam , Country1, 20
2  , Adam , Country1, 21
3  , Ana  , Country3, 22
4  , Rose , Country4, 23
5  , David, Country5, 24
];

Employee_Link:
Load
  Id,
  AutoNumberHash128(Name, Country) as NameCountryLink
Resident
  Employee
;

left join

Load
  Id2                                as IdMeasure,
  AutoNumberHash128(Name2, Country2) as NameCountryLink
Resident
  Employee2
;

// Optional - we can drop NameCountryLink if we dont need it anymore
// Drop Field NameCountryLink;
```

Comment: Thank you very mutch, it work wonderful! I would want to do it by qlik sense because I have  a Table with a lot of columns and I want to choose every time another combination in the AutoNumberHash128 function. Do you have any idea? Thank you!

Comment: You can always pre-set the required fields in a vaiable: `set vFieldsList = MyField1, Myfield2, MyField3;` and then use the variable content inside the function: `AutoNumberHash128($(vFieldsList))`

Comment: I want to show few combination In one show in the same sheet. And I want to allow customer to choose the combination. Is there a possible way?